# Implementation of scrollable tabs in android

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I want to implement scrollable tabs in my app.

I have some content like image, some text views to show the information of the page and a viewpager that is showing the tabs at the bottom.

My problem with the viewpager is, the content keeps loading at that same place whenever I slide or click on any tab.

What I want is that:

1. the swipe of the tabs should be disabled and only click event should work on the tabs like buttons.
2. whenever I click on any tab that fragment should load in the full
   page, like an activity.

How can I achieve this?

My layout xml is:

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="200dp">
        </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have first? Then we can see what needs to be added/changed

Comment: <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp">
        </com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: I am having the above layout with a imageView and some textviews also.

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager> and below I added the viewpager also after the above layout. Now I want to open a new Activity like layout when click on each tab. 

Please help me here, how can I achieve this.

Comment: please add the second comment of yours, like I added the first one, to your post (hit `edit` button)... This is part of your question, not a comment